# mysql check if last update was 3 minutes ater

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have mysql table with column type timestamp
in every 3 minutes I`m updating this table.

and I need to check if last update was 3 minutes later

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE time_stamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND `id` = 2
 LIMIT 1
```

something like this.
but I need to return 1 as isset if time_stamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE
else if must return 0 as isset

how can I create this quesry?

Comment: You can use CASE expression in the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the MySQL control flow functions documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

In particular, look at `IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)`

Comment: I know select xase but I do not understand how to use it in my query. can you please create query for me.?

Comment: SELECT IF(time_stamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE,1,0) AS `isset`
  FROM Table1
 WHERE  `id` = 2
 LIMIT 1;

is it right sintax?